# Creating a React component library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am creating a modular component library with React and TypeScript with Babel 7.

I want the user of my library to import the components by a syntax similar to this:

```
import SomeComponent from "my-awesome-lib/SomeComponent"
```

SomeComponent is a TSX module in my-awesome-lib package:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function () {
  return <h1>SomeComponent</h1>
}
```

And `main` field of the package.json file of my-awesome-component is:

```
"main": "src/index.ts"
```

I do not want to publish compiled version of my component library, because I am importing CSS and other assets in my components and I expect all the users of my package to use Webpack with some specific configs.

Now my problem is that `import SomeComponent from "my-awesome-lib/SomeComponent" fails with a parse error:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/wtf/index.tsx 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default function () {
>   return <h1>WTF</h1>
| }
```

It seems Webpack does not load or transform the TSX files in node_modules.

I use this tsconifg.json at the root of my user app (which imports my-awesome-lib):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "dom", "scripthost"], 
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "node_modules/**/*"],
  "exclude": []
}
```

And the relevant configurations of Webpack are:

```
const tsModules = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  include: [path.resolve('src')],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
}

const resolve = {
  alias: {
  },
  modules: [
    'node_modules'
  ],
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
}

module.exports = {
   ...
   context: resolve('src'),
   resolve: resolve,
   module: {
     rules: [
       tsModules,
       ...
     ]
   }
}
```

How can I make Webpack to load and transform TSX modules of my-awesome-lib from node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

This setup assuming you are using styled-components and have no css/scss.

What's important here is that you have "module": commonJS in your tsconfig and libraryTarget: "commonJS" in your webpack config. Externals tells webpack not bundle you're library with React, or React-DOM or styled-components and instead to look for those packages within the project you're importing into.

you're also going to need to take React, react-dom and styled-components out of your package.json dependencies and put those package in your peer-dependencies

```
   const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
    const appIndex = path.join(__dirname, "../src/main.tsx");
    const appBuild = path.join(__dirname, "../storybook-static");
    const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

    module.exports = {
        context: fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()),
        mode: "production",
        bail: true,
        devtool: false,
        entry: appIndex,
        output: {
            path: appBuild,
            filename: "dist/Components.bundle.js",
            publicPath: "/",
            libraryTarget: "commonjs"
        },
        externals: {
            react: {
                root: 'React',
                commonjs2: 'react',
                commonjs: 'react',
                amd: 'react'
            },
            'react-dom': {
                root: 'ReactDOM',
                commonjs2: 'react-dom',
                commonjs: 'react-dom',
                amd: 'react-dom'
            },
            "styled-components": {
                root: "styled-components",
                commonjs2: "styled-components",
                commonjs: "styled-components",
                amd: "styled-components"
            }
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        parse: {
                            ecma: 8,
                        },
                        compress: {
                            ecma: 5,
                            warnings: false,
                            comparisons: false,
                            inline: 2,
                        },
                        mangle: {
                            safari10: true,
                        },
                        output: {
                            ecma: 5,
                            comments: false,
                            ascii_only: true,
                        },
                    },
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    sourceMap: false,
                })
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".web.js", ".mjs", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
            alias: {
                "react-native": "react-native-web",
            },
        },
        module: {
            strictExportPresence: true,
            rules: [
                { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
                {
                    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                    loader: require.resolve("tslint-loader"),
                    enforce: "pre",
                },
                {
                    oneOf: [
                        {
                            test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
                            loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
                            options: {
                                configFileName: 'tsconfig.prod.json'
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new TsConfigPathsPlugin()
        ],
        node: {
            dgram: "empty",
            fs: "empty",
            net: "empty",
            tls: "empty",
            child_process: "empty",
        },
        performance: false,
    };
```

note: it's important that you target a point in you're application as an entry that ONLY has the components you want to export.

I.E For me it's Main.tsx and inside Main.tsx it looks like this.

```
export { Checkbox } from "./components/Checkbox/Checkbox";
export { ColorUtils } from "./utils/color/color";
export { DataTable } from "./components/DataTable/DataTable";
export { DatePicker } from "./components/DateTimePicker/DatePicker/DatePicker";
export { DateTimePicker } from "./components/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker";
export { Disclosure } from "./components/Disclosure/Disclosure";
```

This means webpack won't bundle things you're not meaning to export. To test you're bundle works try importing something with require syntax from the bundle to get around typescript typings and turn allowJS true in tsconfig.

something like
const Button = require("../path/to/js/bundle").Button
console.log(Button);

Answer (score 1):

I found [`create-react-library`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) extremely helpful

Comment: One more [tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-component-lib), explained in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-library-of-react-components-using-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d182df690c6b)

Answer (score 1):

You are excluding your `node_modules` directory (which generally is a good thing):

```
const tsModules = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  include: [path.resolve('src')],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

Besides explicitely excluding the `node_modules` folder, you also only allow the content of the `src` folder to be processed by `babel-loader` because of your `include` property in `tsModules`. So this error:

> ERROR in ../node_modules/wtf/index.tsx 4:9 Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (4:9)

makes sense.

You can still exclude `node_modules` except for a single folder if you remove the `tsModules.include` property and change your regular expression in `tsModules.exclude`:

```
const tsModules = {
  // ...
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!my-awesome-lib)\/*/
  // ...
}
```

Or you could, but I haven't tested it yet, add the `my-awesome-lib` dir to the `include` array:

```
const tsModules = {
  // ...
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, './node-modules/my-awesome-lib')
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Then files in your `node_modules/my-awesome-lib` directory will pass the `babel-loader` which will transform the typescript code.

**Edit:** I think you confusion is coming from your `tsconfig.json` file with `"include": ["src/**/*", "node_modules/**/*"],`. Babel is transpiling your code, not typescript. So having a `tsconfig.json` file in your root directory may help your IDE (especially if you are using Microsoft's VScode), but has no effect on how `babel` and `@babel/preset-typescript` transform your code.

Comment: Your solution should have worked, but I tried both options and their combination, but I am still getting the same error about not using an 'appropriate loader'.

Comment: And if you comment out the `context` and `resolve` property from your `webpack` config?

Comment: also, did you add both `@babel/preset-typescript` and `@babel/preset-react` to your babel configuration? Babel cannot transpile typescript without the typescript preset.